# Умножение элементов списка Haskell

Tags: список, haskell

Помогите, пожалуйста, с написанием программы, которая делает следующее:

> Описать функцию, которая на основе списка чисел формирует список-
>   результат следующим образом: первый элемент есть произведение
>   элементов списка, второй– произведение элементов хвоста, третий–
>   произведение элементов хвоста хвоста и так далее. Пример: для
>   списка‘(1 2 3 4 5 6) результатом будет: ‘(720 720 360 120 30 6).

```
import Data.List

newlist :: [Int] -> [Int]
newlist list = do
     let elem = list . product
     elem : newlist
     list . drop 1
     newlist list

main = do
    list <- getList
    print newlist list
```

Выводит ошибки типов в 5,6,7,11,12 строках.

Comment: Определение `newlist` какое-то странное. Как будто вы рассчитываете, что ваши действия **изменяют** `list`. Это ж Haskell, тут так не бывает.

Comment: Я пытаюсь сделать именно как создание нового массива и добавление в него элементов.

Comment: И где там, по-вашему, "новый массив"?

Comment: Ну я думал что newlist вернет новый массив

Comment: А что такое newlist?

Comment: Функция, как я думаю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
newlist [] = []
newlist (x:xs) = (product (x:xs)):newlist xs
```

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо!